# Javascript ceases after out-of-page click Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Rails noob and even more pathetic Javascript über noob here.  I have the following code in my static.js file, which works properly ***until*** I click my cart show page, and return to the home page.

```
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this.hash).position().top
    }, 1200);
    return false;
  });
});
```

When I return to the homepage after this trip to the cart view, the nav no longer smooth scrolls to the anchors, just hops to them as if there were no js there. How to keep this smooth scroll permanently is my question. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log` inside the function to see if it gets called? You can also add `debugger` to act as a breakpoint and step through the code in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Turbolinks**

The problem will almost certainly be with [`Turbolinks`](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) - a third-party JS which basically pulls only the `<body>` tag of pages which you've accessed by clicking a turbolinks-enabled link.

The problem with Turbolinks is that because it leaves the `<head>` part of your pages intact, it actually prevents JS from binding to the new elements it appends to the DOM, leading to the problems you're facing

The way around this are either to [delegate javascript](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate), or hook into the [Turbolinks events](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) callbacks. I tend to use both where I can:

--

**Delegation**

Delegation is when you bind a javascript event to a "stable" element of the DOM, *delegating* the event call through to the element you wish.

This is used when the elements in your DOM are constantly changing (as with Turbolinks), and you need to bind your elements "on the fly". This is often done with Ajax requests, as the DOM will change depending on new data coming from the server:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", ".your_element", function(){
   // will delegate from "document" (which is always present), to .your_element
});
```

--

**Turbolinks Events**

Because `$(document).ready` does not work under Turbolinks (it overrides this with its own functions), you'll have to use one of the `Turbolinks` events (typically `page:load`):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var your_function = function(){
  // do something here
}
$(document).on("page:load ready", your_function);
```

---

**Fix**

Try this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.hash).position().top
  }, 1200);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Excellent, this worked, and I appreciate the extra information as well.  Thank you Rich.